# Is the Ring of Symmetric Functions complete?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, symmetric-functions

So, this question came up in a discussion today and I thought I'd post it here. Given that the ring of symmetric functions $\Lambda$ can be equipped with the Hall scalar product. Is it also a complete metric space?

Edit: Supposing that it is false I thought an amusing counter example might be using the sequence

\begin{equation}(e_{0}, e_{0}+e_{1},e_{0}+e_{1}+e_{2},\dots)\end{equation}

As the limit would result in Macdonalds classic example of an element of $\hat{\Lambda}$ with

\begin{equation}\prod_{i \geq 1}(1 + x_{i}) = \sum_{i \geq 0}e_{i}.\end{equation}

Of course this sequence would need to be Cauchy and there lies the problem. If we allow rational coefficients rather than just integer coefficients we could instead consider elements of the form

\begin{equation}\sum_{i=0}^{j}\frac{e_{i}}{(i+1)^{2}} \Rightarrow (e_{0}, \frac{1}{4}(e_{0}+e_{1}), \frac{1}{9}(e_{0},e_{1},e_{2}),\dots).\end{equation}

Here the limit is indeed going to have unbounded degree so we have a counterexample for $\Lambda_{\mathbb{Q}}$. However, for sticking with the more classical integer coefficients. I think this requires all the Cauchy sequences to be sequences that stabilise. Which would mean that it is indeed complete, but the only Cauchy sequences are rather uninteresting.

Edit 2: Obviously not a Hilbert space, my definition was bad.

Comment: What a wicked question from a new contributor.

Comment: This looks pretty correct to me — the Hall-norm of a symmetric polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}$ is going to be a member of $\mathbb{Z}$ itself and so there are no Cauchy sequences that aren't trivial. (ETA: I'm not so sure about this! Symmetric polynomials that have integral coefficients as polynomials don't necessarily have to have integral coefficients in the power-sum basis and so there's no obvious guarantee that a polynomial's norm will be integral.)

Comment: (Thinking about it a little more, I think I might have been right the first time around thanks to the permutation-counting factor in the definition of Hall product, but I'm not nearly confident enough to say for sure.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand the question. If you consider only symmetric functions over $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$ you don't even have a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ so you certainly don't have a Hilbert space. If you consider symmetric functions over $\mathbb{R}$ then symmetric functions over $\mathbb{R}$ are countable-dimensional, and infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces must be uncountable-dimensional. Explicitly, the Schur polynomials $s_{\lambda}$ form an orthonormal basis with respect to the Hall inner product (in the *Hamel*, not the Hilbert space, sense) but no nontrivial infinite sum $\sum c_{\lambda} s_{\lambda}$ converges, even the ones satisfying $\sum |c_{\lambda}|^2 < \infty$.

Comment: My apologies. I realised the mistake in asking if it’s a Hilbert space earlier but neglected to correct it. I’ll do so now. Rather than asking if it is a vector space and a complete metric space (Hilbert). I intended to more simply ask if it is a complete metric space. Specifically with respect to the metric induced by the Hall scalar product.

Comment: @Bats: if you work over $\mathbb{Z}$ then the metric is discrete, so it's complete but for a boring reason, namely that Cauchy sequences are eventually constant.